# Why Wouldn't this Binary Division Program Display the Correct Quotient?

Tags: python, math, binary, division

```
import comparator, bitwise_operator

def divide(dividend, divisor, quotient_remainder):
    operand = []
    divisor_length = len(divisor)
    try:
        for value in range(divisor_length):
            operand.append(dividend.pop(0))
            divisor_length -= 1
    except IndexError:
        for value in range(divisor_length):
            operand.insert(0, 0)
    quotient = []
    remainder = []
    while len(dividend) != 0:
        if comparator.compare(list(operand),
                              list(divisor)) in [[1, 1], [1, 0]]:
            quotient.append(1)
            operand = bitwise_operator.operate(
                list(operand),
                list(divisor),
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 0])
            operand.append(dividend.pop(0))
        elif comparator.compare(list(operand), list(divisor)) == [0, 1]:
            quotient.append(0)
            operand.append(dividend.pop(0))
    remainder = operand
    while comparator.compare(list(remainder),
                             list(divisor)) in [[1, 1], [1, 0]]:
        remainder = bitwise_operator.operate(list(remainder),
                                             list(divisor),
                                             [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                                             [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                                             [0, 0])
        quotient = bitwise_operator.operate(list(quotient),
                                            [1],
                                            [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                                            [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                                            [0, 0])
    if quotient == []:
        quotient = [0]
    if quotient_remainder == [1, 0]:
        return(quotient)
    elif quotient_remainder == [0, 1]:
        return(remainder)

def quotient(dividend, divisor):
    return(divide(dividend, divisor, [1, 0]))

def modulo(dividend, divisor):
    return(divide(dividend, divisor, [0, 1]))
```

The module "bitwise operator" does bitwise in operations, in this case, it does subtraction.

The module "comparator" returns 01, 10 or 11 for if A is less than, more than or equal to B.

Ive been trying to make a binary division program for ages, trying the same approach every time. This one has been my most successful, as it displays the correct modulo, but the quotient is off. As far as I know, it correctly follows the binary long division method.

Does anybody know why it doesn't work??? It's really frustrating. Ive looked throug it and fixed mistakes, but how it is right now should be working.

Unfortunately, I cannot give you the imported modules. But could anybody analyse my code and see what I did wrong, i.e. Incorrect binary division method?

Comment: BY THE WAY, "01101001,01110001" is subtraction, "01101001,00010111" is addition. I accidentally stated that it only does subtraction, but in one case it does addition.

Comment: What's with all these lists of 0/1 flags?

Comment: You've chosen a really weird way to structure your program. Is this supposed to simulate how data would be passed around in a hardware CPU? And if so, is that a requirement? It seems like kind of a halfhearted endeavor, considering that storage appears and disappears out of nowhere and gets resized and rearranged in ways nothing like how hardware would do it.

Comment: Commenting your code would really help.  Is "01101001,01110001" a test case in the middle of your subroutine?  Or is it some really magic number?